# How to set up a asp.net application on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I've copied a whole folder which keeps a website inside from a web server to another computer.From the original server I can easily run the web application. Now I need to know what exactly I have to do in order to be able to run the application on the second computer too. I think there are some special considerations with IIS. What and how do I have to set up in IIS?

Comment: Your question is very vague! What version of Windows are you using? What version of IIS? Is it ASP, ASP.NET, plain HTML or some other technology? Do you have these installed?

Comment: Sorry for asking a question without providing th needed information. I didn't actually know what I had to provide.It's windows server 2003.IIS version is 6.0 The application is written on ASP.NET.

Comment: ASP.NET 1, 2, 3, 3.5 or 4? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps.

1. create a new site from left menu By right clicking and add new website.
2. Give physical path to that folder
3. Map with the site url
4. Give permissions to Directory as (like everyone)
5. Set up the default page if (index page is not present in the directory)
6. Set framework which ever you are using.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the IIS Windows component for whatever version of Windows you're using.
2. Create a new site in IIS
3. Point this new site to your web root
4. Configure DNS for the site (maybe using your hosts file)

Comment: I did exactly as you said. Now when I try to run the application it complains about the ReportViewer version in webconfig file. In the webconfig file the reportviewer version is 9.0.0.0 when I change it to 10.0.0.0 it works. Why do I have to change it?

Comment: I'm guessing because you don't have version 9 of ReportViewer installed. I'm not sure what ReportViewer is though...

Comment: You don't have to change it... Unless you have it specified.  You don't need to have the version defined for it to work.  However, if you have a report that requires a specific version you define the version you need.  Defining the version is "Best Practices" because when the website runs and you have none defined it will use the first version available.  You had to change the version because your .Net Framework is different between the two servers.

Answer (score 1):

There are some considerations to make depending on which version of IIS you are using.  It would be helpful to know if you are using 6 or 7.
If you are under 7, you need to copy the site to your IIS directory (typically wwwroot) and then setup the basic settings in IIS by choosing your application pool and such.  Application pools are typically (but not always) setup by .Net Framework.  You may need to setup your default page and set it as an application.  There are many blogs and sites out there that will tell you how to setup this basic functionality but are specific to your application.

Answer (score 0):

For configuring IIS
1. Firstly, in Programs and features go to Turn on and off windows features...in that tick everything under IIS..go to sub folder and tick everything everywhere

2. Go to Internet Explorer> Setting> Internet Options> Advanced> *untick* Show friendly http error messages option
3. Go to IIS manager
   a. In default application pool> advanced settings > Set true enable 32-bit program option
   b. Go to Asp> setting> expand debugging properties> there will an option of error messages some 2nd last or last option that would be false...set it to true..apply changes
4. Run vbscript and asp only in Internet Explorer (edge 10 in developer options for pop ups)